# How can I access attributes of a lazy variable class?

Tags: python

I've made myself a lazy variable class, and used it in another class.  How can I then access the attributes of the lazy variable class?  I have tried `__getattr__` without luck.  Here's an example:

```
class lazyobject(object):
    def __init__(self,varname,something='This is the something I want to access'):
        self.varname = varname
        self.something = something

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj.__dict__.has_key(self.varname):
            print "Already computed %s" % self.varname
            return obj.__dict__[self.varname]
        else:
            print "computing %s" % self.varname
            obj.__dict__[self.varname] = "something else"
            return obj.__dict__[self.varname]

class lazyobject2(lazyobject):
    def __getattr__(self):
        return self.something

class dummy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self.__class__, 'lazy', lazyobject('lazy'))

class dummy2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self.__class__, 'lazy', lazyobject2('lazy'))

d1 = dummy()
d2 = dummy2()

try:
    print "d1.lazy.something - no getattr: ",d1.lazy.something
except:
    print "d2.lazy is already computed - can't get its .something because it's now a string!"
print "d1.lazy - no getattr: ",d1.lazy

try:
    print "d2.lazy.something - has getattr: ",d2.lazy.something
except:
    print "d2.lazy is already computed - can't get its .something because it's now a string!"
print "d2.lazy - no getattr: ",d2.lazy
```

This prints:

```
d1.lazy.something - no getattr:  computing lazy
d2.lazy is already computed - can't get its .something because it's now a string!
d1.lazy - no getattr:  something else
d2.lazy.something - has getattr:  computing lazy
d2.lazy is already computed - can't get its .something because it's now a string!
d2.lazy - no getattr:  something else
```

What I would like it to print:

```
d1.lazy.something - no getattr:  This is the something I want to access
computing lazy
d1.lazy - no getattr:  something else
```

The above example is contrived but I hope gets the point across.  Another way to phrase my question is: How can I bypass the `__get__` method when accessing a class attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to bypass *__get__* when accessing a class attribute is to look it up via the class dictionary rather than using dotted access.

This is easy to demonstrate using function objects.  For example:

```
>>> class A(object):
        def f(self):
            pass

>>> A.f                         # dotted access calls f.__get__
<unbound method A.f>
>>> vars(A)['f']                # dict access bypasses f.__get__
<function f at 0x101723500>

>>> a = A()
>>> a.f                         # dotted access calls f.__get__
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A object at 0x10171e810>>
>>> vars(a.__class__)['f']      # dict access bypasses f.__get__
<function f at 0x101723500>
```

The other piece of information you were missing is that the inherited *__get__* runs before the *__getattr__* which only runs if no attribute is found.  This logic is controlled by *__getattribute__* which is inherited from *object*.  So, if you want to bypass *__get__* you will either need to write a new *__get__* in the subclass or change the lookup logic by defining *__getattribute__* in the subclass.

To fix the *lazyobject2* class, replace the *__getattr__* with:

```
class lazyobject2(lazyobject):

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        # bypass __get__
        return object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')[key]
```

In summary, the key pieces of knowledge used to solve this problem are:

- *[object.__getattribute__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)* controls the lookup logic.
- It first looks for *[__get__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__)* whether defined in the current class or inherited.
- Only if nothing is found, does it attempt to call *[object.__getattr__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)*.
- The above three steps only happen for dotted lookup.
- Those step can be bypassed by directly accessing the dict via *__dict__* or *[vars()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars)*.

The full details of descriptor logic can be found in [this writeup](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) or in [this presentation](http://Descriptor%20Tutorial).